# Microsoft Graph API C#/Core 2.1 - "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graph

I am attempting to create a file in a Sharepoint Site called "My Site" and am running into an "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable." error.

I have the web app registered on AAD with the following permissions on Graph API -- Files.ReadWrite.All, openid, Sites.ReadWrite.All, User.Read

Project is ASP.NET Core 2.1
Nuget Package installed:
Microsoft.Graph v 1.21.0

HomeController.cs - SaveToSharepoint() is called via AJAX.

```
        private const string ClientId = "erasedforprivacy";
        private const string Secret = "erasedforprivacy";
        private const string tenantID = "erasedforprivacy";
        private GraphServiceClient graphClient;

        private void LoginToMicrosoft()
        {
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ClientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                .WithClientSecret(Secret)
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
        }

        public JsonResult SaveToSharepoint()
        {
            try
            {
                if(graphClient == null)
                {
                    LoginToMicrosoftGraph();
                }

                Task<Drive> test = Test();
                return Json(test.Result);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                return Json(new { Content = "ERROR", ErrorMessage = "SaveToSharepoint Error : " + ex.InnerException });
            }
        }

        public async Task<DriveItem> CreateFile()
        {

            string fileName = "test.txt";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("blah");

            using (MemoryStream fileContentStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                DriveItem file = await graphClient.Sites["My Site"].Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileContentStream);
                return file;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i figured it out.

```
 DriveItem file = await graphClient.Sites["My Site"].Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileContentStream);
```

Needs to be

```
string sharepointSiteUrl = "mysite.sharepoint.com";
string driveId = "xxxxxfakeReallylongM$idblah";
DriveItem file = await graphClient.Sites[sharepointSiteUrl ].Drives[driveId ].Root.ItemWithPath(fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileContentStream);
```